# Do I need to escape attributes when setting an attribute with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a very simple question, but I had trouble finding the answer on Google. My question is, do I need to escape HTML characters (characters used to delimit HTML tags) when setting element attributes with JavaScript or is it handled automatically? For example, I have a text form for image URL.  When it changes, the preview image `src` attribute is updated like:

```
preview.src=form.value.
```

I tried typing this into the form:

```
"></img><b>test</b><img src="
```

and the browser treats it just like an attribute -- a new element is not created.  But I need to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape any `<`, `>`, `&`, ... it inbetween `"..."` or `'...'` you would only need to escape `\"` or in the other case `\'` if you have some.

if you do it like that: `element.attribute = myVar` you don't need to escape anything in myVar, the Browser will handle it.

By the way, image tags are self closing, don't use `<img ...></img>` use `<img ... />`

Comment: But in my example I had double quotes and it seemed like browser automatically escapes them. Yes it was bad example, I forgot that img is self closing. But I tried something like " style="height:200px; and new style attribute isn't created. So is it browser dependent?

Comment: That was exactly what I meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes:

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test'),
    
    // usign single quoutes as outer quotes,
    // no need to escape double quotes ofhtml attributes in this case
    img = '<img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=IMG" width="400" height="200">';

testDiv.innerHTML = img;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```